# Data Import Wizard - Request File Missing Mapped Fields

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, data-import-wizard, data-import

I'm having an issue using Data Import Wizard to create and/or edit a custom object (Assessment_Through_Deactivation).

I am able to use the wizard to map all of the fields from my CSV (I understand the 90-field limit, and am below that).  The wizard properly shows me and automatically maps all of my fields.

[image: data import wizard field mapping visual]

The upload/update will return successful with 100% success rate. Clicking the 'View Result' to download and see the CSV of the result, you can see, 'success' and 'created' columns return 'true' for my records, and 'errors' column returns null.

[image: view result csv from data import wizard]

However, when I view the records, not all mapped fields have value. To check into this further, I have selected 'View Request' to check what was requested by the Data Import Wizard.  The resulting CSV shows the fields that lack value in the created records were also missing from the Request CSV.

[image: Request CSV from Data Import Wizard]

In the above image, you can see an example where date/time assembly, build status assemble, build status canceled, and shipping were included in the request, but the mapped fields of: date/time created, active, authorized, canceled, deactivated, and technology lifecycle were not included in the request.  I did not receive an error message these fields were not included in the request and would not have known, had I not reviewed the resulting record.

I checked the difference in the 'Date/Time Shipping' field (that was included in the request) against other date/time fields that were not included in the request, and all fields shared the same user permission level and were formatted in the same fashion.

I opened the resulting log in the SF Developer Debug Console when creating these records, but only saw success messages, as technically the request from the import wizard was successful for the fields it contained.

Is there anything else I can check or a reason certain fields may be left off of a Data Import Wizard Request without warning?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to upload the same data using Data Loader.io, and all fields updated as expected.

Benefits to using Data Loader over Data Import Wizard in this case were:

- I was able to create/update records with more than 90 fields at a time - This kept me from having to do multiple imports/updates
- Field/object character limits I would've had in the import wizard (about 4,000 characters total per record) were not an issue with Data Loader.

The major disadvantage to using Data Loader over Data Import Wizard in this case was:

- Data Import Wizard has an option to not trigger flows/process builder/etc. for the records you're updating/importing. Data Loader does not have this option, so I needed to manually deactivate all flows that would've triggered and then reactivate them after the import took place. However, the advantages to using Data Loader over the Import Wizard were much greater than the time it took to deactivate/reactivate active flows.

I have not yet heard from SalesForce Support on this issue and will update this answer when they provide a response.